# Fast way to remove duplicates by id from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and would like to remove duplicates. I'm using php. How to remove duplicate rows (by id).
My array looks like:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 415
            ) 
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 425
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 425
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 426
            )
     )
```

Comment: Any reason why you have a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is the only element of the array, you can walk through the array using [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`array_unique`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), as `array_unique` by itself doesn't work with multidimensional arrays.

```
$foo = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map("serialize", $foo)));
```

If you have other elements, @Ghost's answer is probably better

Answer (score 0):

This will also flatten the array to a 1-dimensional array

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 415,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 425,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 425,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 426,
    ),
);


$data = array_unique(
    array_map('end', $data)
);
var_dump($data);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => 415
    [1] => 425
    [3] => 426
)
```